# 'user_id' doesn't have a default value Error in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my project that I'm working on I have a table of users which i have another table that contains project assigned to them. I'm Using this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/User/{{$user->id}}/projects">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="name"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Enter project description here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit">Add Project for User</button>
</div>
```

And in Controller I'm Using this Code:

```
public function store(User $user)
{
    Project::create([
        'user_id ' => $user->id,
        'name' => request('name'),
        'description' => request('description'),


    ]);


    return back();
}
```

And project table has this Code:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now when I'm adding project for user But I get this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `projects` (`name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at ▶"
```

How I can fixed this?

Comment: is `user_id` fillable? Also it looks like a relationship. It's probably better to go at it via the related model e.g. `$user->projects()->save(['name' => request('name'),'description' => request('description')])`

Comment: @apokryfos Yes use_id is fillable.

Comment: @apokryfos I Add your code in my controller but give this error`"Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array gi`

Comment: Oops. You may need to do `new Project([ that data ])` instead of just the array

Comment: why not to `dd()` the `$user` in the controller and see the attributes ?

Comment: @M.Elwan I'll get the same

Comment: you got the user obj. ? with id ?

Comment: @Honey Inside `store()` can you `dd($user);` on the first line, then post what it outputs?

Comment: If the `user_id` is fillable, why not using hidden input instead ?

Comment: @CaptainInsaneo I give this `User {#195 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}`

Comment: you need to have a look at `#attributes: array:7 [▶]`

Comment: have you checked `user_id` is `integer`? or have to tried `$project = new Project;` then init every attribute value and then `$project->save();`

Comment: this is wrong `store(User $user)` you are not getting `User` model here, it is only an id so make it `store($user_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Editing my view to Offers of friends in stack,such as

```
<form method="POST" action="/User/{{$user->id}}/projects">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="name" placeholder="Enter project description here"></textarea>
</div>
<!--<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Enter project description here"></textarea>
</div>-->

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit">Add Project for User</button>
</div>
```

And Edit my controller such as this code

```
 public function store(User $user)
      {
    Project::create(request(['name', 'user_id']));
    return back();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `POST` for `/User/{{$user->id}}/projects` is routing to `store(User $user)` I think you need to update it to `store($user_id)`.

```
public function store($user_id)
{
    Project::create([
        'user_id ' => $user_id,
        'name' => request('name'),
        'description' => request('description'),


    ]);


    return back();
}
```

The route is just passing the current user's ID, not the User model.

Comment: This will be solution.

Answer (score -1):

That error happened because the `$user->id` value in the store method is not set. If the `user_id` is fillable then using hidden input is an option.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/User/{{$user->id}}/projects">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
           <textarea name="name"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <textarea name="description" placeholder="Enter project description here"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <button type="submit">Add Project for User</button>
        </div>
   </form>
```

and then in the controller :

```
public function store()
{
    Project::create([
        'user_id ' => request('user_id'),
        'name' => request('name'),
        'description' => request('description'),
    ]);
    return back();
}
```

Comment: I'm checking your Answer and give this error `MassAssignmentException
user_id`

Comment: @Honey Are you sure that the `user_id` is fillable ? maybe you need to check it again in the `Project` model, `protected $fillable = ['name','description','user_id'];`

Comment: Yes I'm sure and check it Again and again

Comment: user_id don't save in query but post data list has user_id,Then problem is in controller but i do't know How I Can fixed it